# Ignoring Mechanical Material Properties and Design Implications, in a Compressor, does the Thermal Density of the Blades Affect Efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics, compressors, engines

Consider an ideal adiabatic compressor, ignoring the remainder of the thermodynamic cycle. In this case, the heat flow **q** into and out of the compressor itself is zero, by definition of adiabatic compression. The output shaft work then is:
$$h_{out} - h_{in} = w_{shaft}$$
However, if we then consider the case of a compressor which experiences no losses **excepting** thermal inertia and heating. It follows logically that there would be losses to the output work due to heat energy imparted to the compressor itself. My question is, suppose we have two identical compressors, one which is made of Copper, and one which is made of Steel. If we ignore phase changes and assume that both materials can infinitely absorb heat. Will the losses imparted on the exhaust of the compressors be different in any way? Just because Copper will increase in temperature more than Steel for the same input of energy, does this have any impact on the efficiency of a compressor?

Comment: If the materials infinitely absorb heat - do they just keep increasing in temperature or does the heat go somewhere?

Comment: In this case let's assume they increase indefinitely. I suppose another way of wording the question is the rate at which these materials absorb heat different? Is there any efficiency advantage to using a particular material for the blades/compressor assembly? Is it perhaps a rate of heat rejection question (e.g. at X temperature a material is radiating heat quickly enough into the steam that the energy is no longer lost?)

Comment: So the blade material just increases in temperature - what happens at or after the melting point?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. There is no way the metal can "infinitely absorb heat" and become hotter than the working fluid.

Comment: In the case of this question I'm not really asking an engineering question, moreso a theoretical thermodynamic one. We assume that there is no phase change undergone. If the compressor becomes hotter than the working fluid it will just impart that energy back into the working fluid.